# For what kind of $R$-modules $M$ can we find an element $m\in M$ satisfing that $i:M\to M\otimes_R M, x\mapsto x\otimes m$ is an epimorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ a $R$-module. I'm interested in under what condition we can find an element $m\in M$ satisfing that $i:M\to M\otimes_R M, x\mapsto x\otimes m$ is an epimorphism.

I've found out an easy sufficient condition: there exists $m\in M$ such that, for every $n\in M$, we can find $m'\in M, r_1,r_2\in R$ that satisfy $r_1m'=n$ and $r_2m'=m$ (roughly speaking, every $n\in M$ can be expressed as $\frac{r_1}{r_2}m$, it's also equal to say that every finitely generated submodule of $M$ is contained in a cyclic submodule). But I'm not sure if this condition is necessary, too.

Comment: But is this condition ever satisfied?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I found a sufficient  condition to guarantee it as I posted above.

Comment: @Bernard A simple case is $M = R$ and $m = 1$.

Comment: Tensoring by $R$ is trivial. I meant satisfied in non-trivial cases.

Comment: @Bernard $R = \mathbb Z$, $M = \mathbb Z / (2)$ and $m = 1$.

Comment: @Ayman Hourieh: I know, I meant a module that is not cyclic. With Nakayama's lemma you can prove any such module is *locally* cyclic.

Comment: @Bernard  I'm not sure if $\mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$ is a nontrivial example in your opinion.

Comment: @Censi LI: I don't know. I was looking for a finitely generated, locally cyclic $R$-module.

Comment: @Bernard By "locally cyclic" do you mean a module of which all the finitely generated submodule is **contained** in a cyclic submodule? It seems the equivalent to the sufficient condition I posted. Could you please explain further how to prove that locally cyclic is also necessary with Nakayama's lemma?

Comment: No, I mean that all localisation at prime ideals are cyclic. Of course it is enough to have it at maximal ideals.

Comment: @Bernard So you mean if $R$ is a local ring, then such module must be cyclic? What about $\text{Frac}(R)$?

Comment: It is not finitely generated, unless $R$ is a field.

Comment: @Bernard So you mean a finitely generated such must be locally finite? Thanks for your explanation. I think it's a nice idea.

Comment: I've added some justifications to the above discussion, hoping it will be clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some thoughts about this situation:*

If $M$ is finitely generated, no homomorphism from $M$ to $M \otimes_R M$ can be an epimorphism, unless $M$ is locally cyclic.

Indeed, if there were such an epimorphism, consider a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ and its residual field $k=R_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p}$. Tensoring with $k$ over $R$, there would result an epimorphism:
$$M\otimes_R k\to (M\otimes_R M)\otimes_R k\simeq (M\otimes_R k)\otimes_k(M\otimes_R k)$$
As $\dim_k\bigl((M\otimes_R k)\otimes_k(M\otimes_R k)\bigr)=\bigl(\dim_k(M\otimes_R k)\bigr)^2$, this implies $\dim_k(M\otimes_R k)=0$ or $1$.

Now $M\otimes_R k\simeq M_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak pM_{\mathfrak p}$, Nakayama's lemma implies $ M_{\mathfrak p}$ is a cyclic $R_{\mathfrak p}$-module.

Comment: It seems that locally cyclic is also sufficient if $M$ is finitely generated, so when $R$ is a Dedekind domain, all ideals of $R$ satisfy the property. What do you think about the infinitely generated case when $R=\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 0):

The sufficient condition you described is not necessary. in fact, since $\mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}\otimes\mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}=0$, for any index set $I$, $\mathbb Z_{p^{\infty}}^{(I)}$ meets your requirement.